# Javascript works in all browsers except Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a simple javascript that loads a new stylesheet when a button is pressed...it works fine in every browser except Chrome. It even works fine in Safari, which shares the Webkit engine.

Here's a link to my page: www.evanjackson.net/index-new.html

I've researched the issue and I've tried a bunch of stuff but can't figure it out. The script is in the file "initial.js." Any help would be greatly appreciated!

relevant code:

```
<div onclick="hideStuff('button1'); showStuff('button2'); loadjscssfile('css/custom-theme-reskin2/reskin.css','css'); return false;" id="button1" style="display: block;">
                &nbsp;
</div>

function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
    if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the relevant code here? You can click the '{}' button in the editor to tell it you're pasting code.

Comment: Your page works just fine for me in chrome/mac. Are you sure you don't just have some bad cache?

Comment: Which extensions do you have enabled in Chrome? Can you try it with a fresh installed Chrome?

Comment: It's working on Chrome windows 7 64-bit

Comment: What does your Console in the developer tools tell you?

Comment: Working on Chrome v11 under WindowsXP

Comment: What's supposed to change when the button is clicked - just the button? That much works for me

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything about your problem. Fix it and I'll undo my close vote.

Comment: not loading on chrome 13.0.782.112 m on win 7 64 bit.  Appears to be in a "Pending" state indefinitely.  Also looks busy trying to load a lot of m4a files.  Also, interesting that the type for the request is "undefined" (browser doesn't know its text/css mime type).  Loading the link (http://www.evanjackson.net/css/custom-theme-reskin2/reskin.css) in a separate tab using chrome takes me ages, but it eventually loads.

Comment: @Sam ...kinda what I just said.

Comment: @tybro0103 - sorry!  I should've checked for updates before making that last comment.

Answer (score 3):

I am experiencing this as well and may have some insight. I'm using Chrome 13.0.782.112 on Mac OSX Lion.

Browsers limit the number of requests that can be made for external files on a per domain basis. If you open Chrome's developer tools and look at the network tab, you can see the request made for the .css file and it puts it in a pending state. Look more closely and you'll see there are about a dozen other files still trying to load from the same domain. My guess is one or more of these files is either really big or the server just isn't responding. This would cause the browser to not load other files from the same domain.

**UPDATE**
A request is made to this file: http://www.evanjackson.net/music/track_1.m4a and many other .m4a tracks, and the server is not responding. Since the .css file is on the same domain, Chrome is waiting for these .m4a files to load first.

**Looks like certain versions of Chrome can't handle .m4a files until they are completely loaded.**

Comment: I can't load his css file even in a separate tab (using chrome, firefox is fine).  Phrogz - Try linking directly to that css file (take the javascript out of the equation).  It appears that chrome isn't loading that file for some other reason.  While debugging, the size of that file is always 0 and the download is indefinitely left in a pending state.  I do agree with tybro0103 that you are loading a lot of resources all at once, I just don't think that's the root of the problem.  Perhaps add a test page to also take the other file loading out of the equation as well.

Comment: @Sam That's because you still have the page open in another tab. Close the other tab, and it loads instantly.

Comment: Confirmed - closing the original link and THEN loading the css file does load the css file instantly.  I think tybro0103 has the right answer.  Those other resources must be holding up the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

As there is not enough information i can only guess:

I guess, that you have any extension enabled which collides with your code or there is some bad code in your cache.

You may try the following:

1. Clear the browser cache
2. Disable all extensions
3. Restart your browser
4. Give us some feedback ;-)

Comment: Sorry...I didn't provide enough info. When you click the "Load a new Style sheet" button it's supposed to fire a Javascript that changes the button (which it does) and also loads a new style sheet that totally changes the imagery and looks of the site (which it doesn't). Thanks for all of your responses so far...very helpful. I think it has something to do with one of my files taking too long to load...I'm investigating now. Thanks again!